# Are Biggs & Wedge in or referenced in Final Fantasy XIII-2?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

Are Biggs and Wedge in Final Fantasy XIII-2 or is there an item or place named after them like in XIII? I've yet to clear the game but I'm curious about this.

Comment: Wait, there was a Biggs and Wedge reference in XIII? I must have missed that.

Comment: @Shinrai It's the name of a store, the B&W Outfitters as you can see here :) http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Biggs_and_Wedge

Comment: Oh, I never caught that 'B&W' = 'Biggs and Wedge'.

Comment: wha...Biggs and Wedge from *Star Wars*? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately they do not make an appearance in this Final Fantasy. Although a common theme, they are actually not involved in all of the series so far. However, Cid in some form, features in every game I believe.

You can find a [list of all Biggs & Wedge references here](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Biggs_and_Wedge)